# Read TOC (not Bookmarks) from a PDF using iText or PDFBox

Tags: pdf, itext, pdfbox, tableofcontents

I need to extract **Table of contents** (TOC) from an input PDF file. All the code I have seen so far refer to Bookmark. 
TOC and Bookmarks are **NOT** the same thing.
Is there a way to extract the TOC from the pdf using iText or PDFBox. I am open to using any other tool available.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The table of contents of a PDF you refer to, is nothing more than ordinary text on a page. Hence your only option is to extract the text on the pages that contain the TOC, for instance using the code shown in the [ExtractPageContentSorted2](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=296) example:

```
public void parsePdf(String pdf, String txt) throws IOException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(txt));
    for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
        out.println(PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, i));
    }
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

This example extracts the text of *all* the pages in the PDF and writes it to a file with path `txt`. If you want this code to extract only the pages with the table of contents, you are going to have to change the page numbers in the `for` loop, for instance:

```
for (int i = startTOC; i <= endTOC; i++)
```

where `startTOC` is the page number where the TOC starts and `endTOC` the page number where the TOC ends. **You** need to provide these numbers, because the PDF document as such isn't aware of the fact that the content on those pages are, in fact, a Table of Contents. The PDF only knows that the pages contain text and rendered paths and maybe some images. That is inherent to PDF.